Linear transformations and non-eigenvectors
Suppose $X$ is an infinite dimensional vector space and $T:X \to X$ is a bijective linear transformation different from the identity:

Can one find countably infinite many linear independent vectors that are not eigenvectors ?.
If $X$ has an uncountable basis, can one find uncountably many linear independent vectors that are not eigenvectors ?.


If $T = \lambda$ is a scalar multiple of the identity then every vector in $X$ is an eigenvector of $T$, so the answer is no in this case. The answer is yes in every other case and a "generic" choice of vectors works.
We can argue as follows. For a scalar $\lambda$ write $X_{\lambda} = \ker(T - \lambda)$ for the $\lambda$-eigenspace. It is still true that the subspaces $X_{\lambda}$ are linearly independent and the proof is the same as in the finite-dimensional case. So we have an injection
$$\bigoplus_{\lambda} X_{\lambda} \hookrightarrow X$$
from the direct sum of the eigenspaces to $X$ (which need not be injective, and in fact the LHS can be zero). Let $W$ be any complement of the image, so that we can write
$$X = \left( \bigoplus_{\lambda} X_{\lambda} \right) \oplus W.$$
($W$ is not necessarily $T$-invariant but we don't need this.) With respect to this direct sum decomposition, a vector is an eigenvector iff it has exactly one nonzero component and this component lies in $X_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda$.
Now it suffices to choose any basis of $X$ in which every vector has at least two nonzero components with respect to this decomposition; this is always possible if $T$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity, and in fact the "generic" basis consists of vectors with all components nonzero (you can think of these as being chosen "randomly" in some suitable sense). The details can be spelled out but it would be a bit tedious.

Can one get something stronger? Namely, finding an infinite dimensional subspace $Z$ such that $Z\cap T(Z)={0}$?

@Markus: I don't know off the top of my head. I'd have to think more about the structure of arbitrary $K[T]$-modules. Do you have any particular motivation for asking these questions?

No particular reason. I was just thinking how far can a linear transformation be from the identity, in the sense above.
